# Yii passing variables from class to dropDownList

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I'm trying to make dropDownList in _form view.

This is the Controller part

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $modelCountry = Country::model()->findAll();
    $this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,'modelCountry'=>$modelCountry,
    ));
}
```

Now in _form view I have a TextField which must be modified to dropDownList

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name_en'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'name_en',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'name_en'); ?>
</div>
```

That means I must modify it to something like this

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'name_en',array('!Variable!A!From_modelCountry!','!Variable!B!From_modelCountry!' )); ?>
```

I can use foreach loop and inside that loop create some DropDownList but maybe there is some better way to take data out of an array $modelCountry and put them straight to array of that dropDownList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that. In your controller you can write

```
    $list=CHtml::listData($modelCountry,'id','name_en');
$this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,'modelCountry'=>$modelCountry,'list'=>$list
    ));
```

Now in your View you can write

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'name_en',$list); ?>
```

You can use Chmlt::listData in your view but that should be a part of controller, thats what MVC is all about.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'name_en',CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(),'id','name')); ?>
```